# How to shrink size of DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I am developing a VB.NET app which returns data to a DataGrid.  Everything works correctly now except for one thing.  I want all of the blank white space below my datagrid to not appear, so that users don't have to worry about scrolling down the page.

Currently, it shows the DataGrid correctly, with a scrollbar and this grid takes up about half the height of my monitor.  But then there is alot of empty white space below this grid.  How can I remove that?

Here is the end of my ASPX file:

```
    <head> 
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .DataGridFixedHeader {background-color: #336699; color:White; font-weight: "bold"; position:relative; top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);}
            #txtFind{     width:150;     padding:5px;     outline:none;     height:20px; } 
            .focusField{     border:solid 2px #73A6FF;     background:#EFF5FF;     color:#000; } 
            .idleField{     background:#EEE;     color: #6F6F6F;     border: solid 2px #DFDFDF; }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form runat="Server" defaultbutton= "btnFind" method="post" id="Form1">
            <div style="font-size:18pt; font-family:verdana; font-weight:bold; color:#336699">
               Parts Watch List
            </div>
            <hr style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt; color:#000080;" />
            <div style="height: 380px; text-align: center; position: static;">              
                <input id="part_transfer" type="hidden" runat="server"/>
                <input id="part_desc_transfer" type="hidden" runat="server"/>                               
                <asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign = "Center">
                       <span style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 15pt;">
                            Calculation:</span><br />
                        Reliability Rate &nbsp;=&nbsp; 1 - ( number of failed parts in the last 6 months / Part Multiplier * Average instrument Census in the last 6 months),<br />
                        Where
                        <br />
                        Number of failed parts - Summation of failures of a part for a 6 month period<br />
                        Part Multiplier - Number that represents how many times a part is used on the intrument<br />
                        Average instrument census -&nbsp; Average of the instrument census for the same
                        6 month timeframe as failed parts<br />
                        <br />
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                        Please choose one of the parts below to view the control charts.</p>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel id="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <chart:WebChartViewer id="WebChartViewer1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
            <hr style="width: 90%; position: static;" />

            <div style="text-align: center; position: static; ">
                <asp:Label id="CensusLastUpdate" runat="server"/><br />
                <asp:Button id="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel"></asp:Button>
                <asp:CheckBox id="check1" Text="Display Only Parts Below Threshold" TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="ReRun_Main" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFind" Text="Enter Part Number" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnFind" Text="Search" runat="server" OnClick="SearchTable"  />
            </div> 

            <% Dim scrollPosURL As String = "../includes/ScrollPos.htc"%>
            <input id="saveScrollPos" type="hidden" runat="server" name="saveScrollPos"/>

            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="" > 
                <tr>  
                    <td> 
                        <div style="OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 400px; vertical-align: top; ">  
                            <ASP:DATAGRID ID="dgTable" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="True" OnItemDataBound="DataGrid1_ItemDataBound">
                                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor = "#eeeeee" />
                                <HEADERSTYLE CssClass="ms-formlabel DataGridFixedHeader" /> 
                                <COLUMNS>

                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="PN" DATAFIELD="PART_NUM" READONLY="true" ItemStyle-Width="130px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/>
                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="PART_DESC" DATAFIELD="PART_DESC" READONLY="true" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/>
                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="numFailed" DATAFIELD="NUM_FAILED" READONLY="true" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/>
                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="AvgCensus" DATAFIELD="AVG_CENSUS" READONLY="true" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/>
                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="PartMultiplier" DATAFIELD="PartMultiplier" READONLY="true" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/>
                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="ReliabilityRate" DATAFIELD="RELIABILITY_RATE" READONLY="true" ItemStyle-Width="105px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/>
                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="PRIORITY" DATAFIELD="PRIORITY" READONLY="true" Visible="False" ItemStyle-Width="0px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/> 
                                    <ASP:BOUNDCOLUMN HEADERTEXT="Criticality" DATAFIELD="Criticality" READONLY="true" ItemStyle-Width="105px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="8"/>
                                </COLUMNS>              
                            </ASP:DATAGRID>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>       
        <!-- Javascript at the bottom for fast page loading --> 
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary --> 
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.js">\x3C/script>')</script> 

<!-- Scripts concatenated --> 
<script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<!-- End scripts --> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the style height (currently set to 400px) on the DIV that it lives in.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but this didn't fix it.  All this did was shrink height of my DataGrid.  But all of the whitespace remained.  Any other ideas?